# cancel MouseDown event in WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, mousedown

I've several count variables with min and max values. While I press the appropriate buttons the counter goes up or down.

While pressing the lmb and the counter exceeds e.g. 100 (max value) it doesnt stop counting naturally.

Is there  a way to check my counter and force the end of the mouse event without watching over it manually?

```
private void button_RunXPositive_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (X < 100) {
      StartInMode(0, true); // a motor 
      ((Button_Triangle)sender).BackColor = ((Button_Triangle)sender).EdgeColor;
      return;
    }  
    else {
      ((Button_Triangle)sender).BackColor = Color.Black;
      this.MotorStop((UInt32)0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project is an **WPF** project then you can write this in your event handler:

```
if(counter < min || counter > max)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
//your code
```

**EDIT** If you're using **Windows Form** so you can do this:

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(counter < min || counter > max)
    {
        return;
    }

    //your code
}
```

Comment: I'm using WindowForm and implemented your second tip already but it doesnt stop my counter, as long as I kept it pressed down, it counts and doesnt care for bounds.

Comment: @Hossein Narimani Rad Still not working as it should be, I added some code in my first post. Probably a fault there ?