# Disable the interaction of the mouse with a RichTextBox (all the mouse events to have no influence on the RichTextBox)

Tags: c#, winforms, events

What is the equivalent of e.Handled = true in the KeyDown event handler for the MouseDown event handler?
I wish none the mouse events to have any effect on the RichTextBox (disable completely the interaction of the mouse with the RichTextBox).
More precisely, I wish to prevent the user from marking the text present in the RichTextBox or positioning the cursor anywhere else than the end of the text in the RichTextBox by means of the mouse.

Comment: Take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763343/cancel-mousedown-event

Comment: Sorry, the: return in the event handler does not prevent from marking the text present in the RichTextBox.

Comment: just want to clarify: You are saying you want to prevent user to put the cursor anywhere, is it because you want to write something from your program always started at the end of your rich text box?

Comment: I want to force the user to only be able to append to the text already in the RichTextBox or to delete the last character, using BackSpace.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to kill off any selection before it begins:

```
rtb.SelectionChanged += (sender, e) => { rtb.SelectionStart = rtb.TextLength; };
```